# Callback function "C style" called from C++ object

Tags: c++, callback

I'm learning on the field about callback functions. Thanks to some of you I learned much.
I'm using a C++ instance of an object that must call a callback function: a single function, not a C++ method as the follow:

```
MyObj *obj = new MyObj();

obj->callback(function);

//callback 
void funtion() 
{
  int i = 10;
  ...
}
```

My doubt is the following:
if different  instances of MyObj invoke the callback, do they will create different "instances" of "function" with their own local variables? in other words are there different "i = 10" in memory for each object invocation or the risk is that the same "i" is shared?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "instance" of a function. All local variables of a function, member or free-standing, are placed in the automatic storage area (also known as "on the stack"). These variables stay in the automatic storage area until they are no longer needed because their scope has ended, and then get discarded.

Each thread running your function concurrently will have its own copy of the local variables - in your case, each one will have its own `i`.

Note that if you want to share a variable among multiple invocations, C++ lets you do that by marking the variable inside the function `static`:

```
void funtion() 
{
    static int i = 10;
    ...
}
```

Now all invocations of `function` share the same variable `i`. Moreover, the value of `i` will persist across multiple invocations: for example, if one call sets `i` to 20 before exiting, and then another call enters the function, the value of `i` would remain 20, not 10, because the initialization of `i` is performed only once in the run time of your program.

Comment: Yes, I know about static and shareble variables. For my scope, it needs that every calllback invocation, using different objects, doesn't share the same variables, in other word, obj1->callback has his own i variable and obj2->callback too (in this case for instance,  I'm free to change the i variable without worry for each obj). Thank you again.